# Substitution in a power transformed in product

Tags: replacement

This could be thought as a duplicate question but it's in fact an extension of an old section.

```
 1 + (a (α + β))/(b^2 + c^2) + ((α + β)^2 a^2)/(b^2 + c^2)
```

could be simplified by introducing

```
d = a/(b^2 + c^2)
γ = α + β
```

A simple substitution solution cannot work a shown by L. Shifrin who has programmed a nice but complicated solution.

Some solutions as the one in "Expanding out multiplied terms" question in this site seems to give a solution expanding $x^3$ as $x x x$. But unfortunately, it is impossible to  substitute  $A$ to $x x$

In the case described above applying the proposed substitution does not work.

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452555/how-to-replace-implicit-subexpressions-in-mathematica There is also a solution provided - `withExpandedPowers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the substitution rule a little bit to avoid the power.

```
(1 + (a (α + β))/(b^2 + c^2) 
   + ((α + β)^2 a^2)/(b^2 + c^2)) /. a -> d (b^2 + c^2)
```

> ```
> 1 + d (α + β) + (b^2 + c^2) d^2 (α + β)^2
> ```